# memcpy or std::copy for my particular application

Tags: c++, algorithm, memcpy

I'm attempting to author a `C++` wrapper to some legacy `C` code to increase it's type safety and make it less of a PITA to use. The legacy code interacts with pointers in shared memory. POD structures are cast from these pointers. Since it's shared memory, these structures are guaranteed to be POD.

The `C` code is littered with `memcpy` instances. I was wondering if it would be a good idea to use `std::copy` rather than `memcpy` in this instance, or if it would be better to leave it alone.

For example, the original code (represented in pseudo-code):

```
// we cast from a void pointer return from the shared memory segment
void *ptr = FunctionToReturnPointer();
descriptor_p = (descriptor_t*)new char[sizeof(descriptor_t)];
memcpy(descriptor_p, ptr, sizeof(descriptor_t));
```

where `descriptor_t` is a POD structure. In my solution, I'd probably do something like this (represented in pseudo-code):

```
// provide a casting class that can do everything
template <typename T>
class CastClass {
    static T* Cast() {
        void *ptr = FunctionToReturnPointer();
        T *t = new T;
        std::copy(ptr, ptr + sizeof(T), t);
        return t;
    }
};

// And how I would use the function
descriptor_p = CastClass<descriptor_t>::Cast();
```

So here are my questions:

1. Is it beneficial to do this? Or is this a fool's errand?
2. Am I adding any type-safety to the code?
3. Is my usage of `std::copy` algorithm correct?

Comment: Hmmm, consider [does it work](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v102/Arsenaultb/flowchart.jpg)?

Comment: @chux Not my call to make it "fancy", nice graphic though!

Comment: Most likely code would run slower. Memcpy is highly tuned function, using SSEx instructions and what not to do copy really fast.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The only way to know is to measure. `std::copy` will probably invoke `memcpy` under the hood anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza concur. On my implementation trivially-copyables have `std::copy` overloads that do just that.

Comment: When in doubt, leave it alone...probably the last thing you want to have happen is for something to blow up on you because you changed it to use std::copy in place of memcopy and have to go back and revert all your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to dynamically allocate copies on the heap at all?

```
// provide a casting class that can do everything
template <typename T>
class CastClass {
    public:
    static T Cast() {
        T *ptr = (T*) FunctionToReturnPointer();
        return *ptr; // return a copy of the data
    }
};
```

```
descriptor_t descriptor_p = CastClass<descriptor_t>::Cast();
```

If you do need a pointer, then at least use `unique_ptr` to manage it:

```
// provide a casting class that can do everything
template <typename T>
class CastClass {
    public:
    static std::unique_ptr<T> Cast() {
        T *ptr = (T*) FunctionToReturnPointer();
        return new T(*ptr); // return a managed pointer to a copy of the data
    }
};
```

```
std::unique_ptr<descriptor_t> descriptor_p = CastClass<descriptor_t>::Cast();
```

Comment: I like this solution the best. Thank you very much.

Comment: A template class with one function should just be a template function.

Answer (score 2):

How about neither? Just let the the object's default copy assignment work by using properly typed pointers:

```
descriptor_t* descriptor_p = new descriptor_t;
*descriptor_p = *(descriptor_t*)(FunctionToReturnPointer());
```

One line:

```
descriptor_t* descriptor_p = new descriptor_t(*(descriptor_t*)(FunctionToReturnPointer()));
```

Template version:

```
template<typename T>
T* MakeNewCopy(void* p) { return new T(*static_cast<T*>(p)); }

auto p = MakeNewCopy<descriptor_t>(FunctionToReturnPointer());
```

This will be much cleaner than what it seems like you have now but the compiler cannot help you if you give the wrong type to the template so "safe" is a relative term. Any time you use a void* and cast it you are taking the gloves off. Try to contain that behavior a much as possible so that your code is almost only ever dealing with properly typed pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::copy(ptr, ptr + sizeof(T), t);
```

is not right.

First of all, I don't think you can pass an object of type `void*` in a call to `std::copy`

Even if you did something like:

```
T* ptr = static_cast<T*>(FunctionToReturnPointer());
...
std::copy(ptr, ptr + sizeof(T), t);
```

there are problems.

Say `T == int` and `sizeof(int)` is `4`.

That usage of `std::copy` will try to copy:

`*t` to `*ptr`
 `*(t+1)` to `*(ptr+1)`
 `*(t+2)` to `*(ptr+2)` and
 `*(t+3)` to `*(ptr+3)`

Your code hasn't allocated memory for those many objects, and will lead to undefined behavior.